# Bad interpreter error trying to execute a script

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I'm trying to start Fritzing using a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
./home/salman/fritzing/Fritzing
```

I did sudo `chmod +x /usr/bin/fritzing` but I get a

> bash: /usr/bin/fritzing: /usr/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied".

What does the bad interpreter mean? And why am I getting a permission denied even after chmoding the bash script which is in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

First you should verify the paths to the binaries:

```
    #which bin   
    #which fritzing
```

Also the second line should be like this , lets assume that path is correct.

```
   /home/salman/fritzing/Fritzing
```

there should be no dot . at the start